# MySQL Count with a condition

Tags: mysql, count

Let's say I have a table which contains cities and names. But in a city, the names are duplicate. How can I count the duplicate names which belong to every distinct city?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select count(name) from Table group by CITY having count(*) > 1
```